# Sandbox an account and prevent it from any system modifications

Tags: command-line, sudo, directory, sandbox

I am trying to sandbox a user account to the point where it cannot edit or view any files beyond a certain folder, namely `/home/user/test`. This account will be compiling and running a C++ program that can subject the system to any command, and it cannot be able to modify or edit the system in any way.

This means disabling `su` and `sudo`, removing write (and some read) permissions from the entire system for this user, and keeping the program locked (jailed) inside its own folder. Is there anything else that I am missing?

---

Now for the implementation.

I believe that I can find the location of `su` and `sudo` by typing `whereis su` and `whereis sudo`, respectively. For `sudo`, for example, I can find that the binaries are at:

`/usr/bin/sudo
/usr/lib/sudo
/usr/bin/X11/sudo
/usr/share/man/man8/sudo.8.gz`

If I change the permissions on these binaries to disallow execution for this user, will that prevent `sudo`ing through other means, such as within other programming languages?

For "jailing" the program within a certain folder, it seems that `chroot` is ineffective, especially if the program needs access to other resources that are outside of the sandboxed folder. What is the best way to do this, then?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to find what you need to include in your chroot than to find out you forgot some program that could be used as a back-door. 
You just make links to the material you need from under the chrooted structure.  And anything you overlooked to include you find out about on the first compile run.

Whenever I had this requirement I have used virtual machines for this kind compilation since 2000. No worries about what such an account does, nor that other activities on the system (software installation etc) could break the compilation process. Easy to make snapshots before upgrading things, etc. 
For that, the overhead of the VM in term of speed degradation is very small price to pay.